# Solution to the Recurrence Equation $a_{n+2}+b_1a_{n+1}+b_2a_n=b_3n+b_4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find a solution to the following problem:

> If $c_12^n+c_23^n+n-7$ is the general solution of 
>   $a_{n+2}+b_1a_{n+1}+b_2a_n=b_3n+b_4$ with $b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4$
>   constants. Calculate the value of the constants.

But I am not sure how to resolve such recurrence equations.

What have I tried?

I thought of dividing the equation into two parts since it is not lineal.

$$
a_n^{(p)} = b_2n+b_4 \\
a_n^{(h)} = a_{n+2}+b_1a_{n+1}+b_2a_n = 0
$$

An from there I thought of solving each equation but in starting with $a_n^{(p)}$ which has the form of a lineal equation of grade 2 in which I converted it to the following form:

$$x^2+b_x+b_2$$

And to find the roots of this equation, I thought of using the discriminant formula in which:

$$
x_1 = -b_1+\frac{\sqrt{b_1^2-4(1)(b_2)}}{2(1)} = -b_1+\frac{\sqrt{b_1^2-4b_2}}{2} \\
x_2 = -b_1-\frac{\sqrt{b_1^2-4(1)(b_2)}}{2(1)} = -b_1-\frac{\sqrt{b_1^2-4b_2}}{2}
$$

Would this be a good way to attempt solving the problem? If not, how am I to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that as the solution to the homogenous part takes the form of $c_1(2)^n + c_2(3)^n$, this means that $2$ and $3$ form the solution to the homogenous part of the recurrence relation. Hence, $2$ and $3$ are the roots to $x^2+b_1 x + b_2=0 \implies b_1 = -5\, , b_2 = 6$.

Now, just substitute the solution $a_n = c_1(2)^n + c_2(3)^n+n-7$ into the recurrence relation to obtain $b_3$ and $b_4$.

Note that $$a_{n+2} - 5a_{n+1}+6a_n = b_3n + b_4$$ $$= c_1(2^{n+2}-5\times 2^{n+1} + 6\times 2^n) + c_2(3^{n+2}-5\times 3^{n+1}+6\times 3^{n})+(n+2-5n-5+6n)-21 $$ $$=c_1(0)+c_2(0)+2n-24 $$ $$\implies \color{green}{2}n \color{blue}{- 24} = \color{green}{b_3}n + \color{blue}{b_4}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit with that last part when you state substituting the solution into the recurrence relation?